# How to calibrate HR202 humidity sensor?

Tags: sensor, humidity

I'm doing a project on humidity monitoring using HR202 Humidity sensor and PIC16F877A.I could not find resolution & accuracy of HR202 in online.So please help me to calibrate and use HR202 humidity sensor(not module).

Comment: I dunno what you're doing wrong. I Googled HR202 Humidity and the second item I got back was www.elecrow.com/download/HR202%20Humidity%20Sensor.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As WhatRoughBeast already mentioned the data sheet is readily available by simply goolgling "HR202 Humidity". [Here is the link](http://www.elecrow.com/download/HR202%20Humidity%20Sensor.pdf). The accuracy and resolution are clearly stated.

Note that the sensor is analogue and requires an AC voltage! It is not a particularly user friendly Humidity sensor for this reason. It is a resistor which changes its resistance based on the humidity of the environment. 
How accurate your final humidity reading will be will also be a function of how accurately you can measure its resistance.

On the datasheet there is a table which tabulates the resistance of the sensor at various Relative Humidity levels given a certain temperature. From this you can create a 2 parameter equation in software which takes the current temperature, and resistance value from the sensor as inputs and calculates your humidity value. 
Note, you will also need a temperature sensor to use this humidity sensor accurately.

**Actually Calibrating a Humidity Sensor:**
Humidity Sensors are notoriously difficult to calibrate, because you need a known Relative Humidity value to calibrate against. The way this is usually done is using saturated salt solutions, which at equilibrium result in known relative humidities. Here is a paper tabulating the produced relative timidities at different temperatures: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/81A/jresv81An1p89_A1b.pdf

From these values you can calibrate your sensor if need be.

Comment: Sir How do I know resistance sir.The HR202 sensor outputs a voltage according to RH.I have added a temperature sensor.also How to create an equation which give me correct RH output? Please help me to learn Sir ...

Comment: That's the problem - the HR202 does NOT output a voltage according to RH. Rather it changes its AC resistance. 

Honestly, my recommendation would be find a different humidity sensor. This sensor doesn't do what you think it does and is not easy to use with a micro-controller such as the PIC. Look for DC humidity sensors from Honeywell or Sensirion (more expensive), or cheaper look at the DHT22.